# Performance issue in iOS-5 for Sqlite

Tags: iphone, objective-c, performance, ios5, sqlite

I am facing one problem while using sqlite in iOS 5. **I am fetching records from two tables: one in Recipe & other in Ingredients from one Menu.db**

From Recipe table I get all record and one `recipeid` on that basis I fetch records from ingredients table. It takes no time to fetch record when run on iOS 4.2 but when I run on iOS 5 it takes time to fetch the records. See the following code:

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select id from Recipes"];
sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
    while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        rcp.recipeID = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
        NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select Name from Ingredients where recipeId = %d",rcp.recipeID];
        sqlite3_stmt *stmt2;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &stmt2, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            while(sqlite3_step(stmt2) == SQLITE_ROW) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Why is this issue coming in iOS 5.0, the same code runs fine on iOS 4.0, 4.2?

I know, code I have written is right,I want to know the exact reason behind this Performance issue in iOS 5.0 for Sqlite bcoz my app is totally build around database.

Comment: In project are create 2 .sql file or not

Comment: I suspect a difference in the database.  (Have you verified that you get the same results in both cases?)

Comment: I have one Menu.db and in that I have two tables.

Comment: Yes I verified in both cases results are same.

Comment: How big the time difference is? Are you finalizing (sqlite3_finalize) your statements?

Comment: its a difference of half second for every record. and Yes I am finalizing the statments. After "sqlite3_prepare_v2" statament

Comment: My question is why this issue is coming in iOS 5.0,the same code runs fine on iOS 4.0,4.2.

Comment: Try GetListBySQL function posted its optimized by memory & execution cycles.

Comment: You should also try a Key/Value Database (Like LevelDB or TokyoCabinet)), it could be a big effort right now to change, but is blasting fast.

Comment: @Raspu: Can you provide some link about LevelDB & TokyoCabinet from where I can get right information

Comment: I'll make an answer with it, wait.

Answer (score 1):

Try with using two different functions
After you finish with complete execution of your first query, start with second query.

For example :-

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select id from Recipes"];
sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
    while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        rcp.recipeID = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
    }
}
```

and then call

```
 NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select Name from Ingredients where recipeId = %d",rcp.recipeID];
            sqlite3_stmt *stmt2;
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &stmt2, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
                while(sqlite3_step(stmt2) == SQLITE_ROW) {}
```

Hope this helps to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you linked against `libsqlite3.dylib`. You should link the `libsqlite3.0.dylib` library instead.

Comment: I have used  libsqlite3.0.dylib .

Answer (score 1):

If you want  contever your .db to .sqlite

open your .db file select the table    File-> Export--> Table from CSV (save your file with .csv format) 
(like this way you select all table)
then open .sqlite file
 File-> Import--> Table from CSV 
after your .csv file choose a dialog box appear
in that Extract field names from first line must tick marked
now your sqlite file is ready.

put this file into your project

then set your .sqlite/.db file path

now set your select query as like this

```
#import <sqlite3.h>


    -(void)SelectSqlData:(NSString *)SearchString
    {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourfileName.sqlite"];
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        sqlite3 *database;
        if(sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

            const char *sqlStatement;

            sqlStatement = "select c.field1,c.field2,c.field3,c.field4 from YourTableName1 as c,  YourTableName2 as b  where b.Artist_Id = ?"; 

            sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL);

            //printf("\nError===%s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));


            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

                sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement,1,[SearchString UTF8String] , -1,SQLITE_STATIC);

                while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW ) 

                {

                        NSString *str_field1=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];

                        NSString *str_field2=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];

                        NSString *str_field3=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];

                        NSString *str_field4=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];


    // add str_field into array


            }

            }

            sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);


        }


        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't the answer you're looking for, but here's a small tip to improve performance.

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select id from Recipes"];
sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
    while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        rcp.recipeID = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select Name from Ingredients where recipeId = %d",rcp.recipeID];//
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        sqlite3_stmt *stmt2;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &stmt2, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            while(sqlite3_step(stmt2) == SQLITE_ROW) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Every iteration of the `while` loop, you create a new NSString object (`NSString *sql = ...`), so maybe you should instead do this:

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select id from Recipes"];
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select Name from Ingredients where recipeId = %d",rcp.recipeID];
sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
    while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        rcp.recipeID = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
        sqlite3_stmt *stmt2;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &stmt2, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            while(sqlite3_step(stmt2) == SQLITE_ROW) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps a bit!

Answer (score 1):

The function GetListBySQL is optimized and iOS versions independent. May it will help you out.

```
-(NSMutableArray*)GetListBySQL:(NSString*)SQL
{
NSMutableArray* Array;

Array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSStringEncoding enc = [NSString defaultCStringEncoding];

sqlite3_stmt *select_statement=nil;

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [SQL UTF8String], -1, &select_statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSString *errString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [@"Fail" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:[NSString stringWithCString:sqlite3_errmsg(database) encoding:enc] ]];
    NSAssert1(0, @"%@", errString);
}

int columncount=sqlite3_column_count(select_statement);

NSMutableDictionary* dic;

while (sqlite3_step(select_statement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
{   
    dic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    for(int j=0;j<columncount;j++)
    {
        if(sqlite3_column_text(select_statement, j)!=nil)
            [dic setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(select_statement, j)] forKey:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_name(select_statement,j)]];
        else
            [dic setObject:@"" forKey:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_name(select_statement,j)]];
    }

    [Array addObject:dic];
    [dic release];      
}

sqlite3_finalize(select_statement);

NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: Array];

[Array release];

return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to change SQLite to a Key/Value database like LevelDB (from google) or TokyoCabinet. I'm using LevelDB for two project right now and is working really good, and I used TokyoCabinet in the past also, the problem with TokyoCabinet is that is LGPL, so I'm not sure if is fully compatible with the iOS environment, but anyway I had several Apps in the appstore using Tokyo Cabinet (don't tell Apple).

For using both of them you will need a wrapper (Or maybe you can develop your own). This is a quick comparison and the available wrappers:

- [LevelDB](http://code.google.com/p/leveldb/): It seems to be one of the fastest out there (if not the fastest, take a look at their [benchmarks](http://leveldb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/benchmark.html)). And as wrapper I'm currently using [NULevelDB](https://github.com/nulayer/NULevelDB), if you have any problems adding it to your project let me know (I had some).
- [TokyoCabinet](http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/): It seems to be no so fast as LevelDB (I haven't run tests, I dropped it because of the license problems), but in the official page they recommend using their new library called [KyotoCabinet](http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/) that I haven't tested yet but is supposed to be faster. The wrapper I used was made by the amazing [Aaron Hillegass](http://www.bignerdranch.com/), and it is called [BNRPersistence](https://github.com/hillegass/BNRPersistence).

As a recommendation, give a try to LevelDB, there is a bigger community behind, and the wrapper ([NULevelDB](https://github.com/nulayer/NULevelDB)) is simple and friendly.

Good luck!